# Does the for loop invocation result in fetching all records from the database and is there a way to control this behaviour?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

```
using (AdventureWorksEntities context = new AdventureWorksEntities())
{
    var query = context.Products
        .Select(product => new
        {
            ProductId = product.ProductID,
            ProductName = product.Name
        });

    Console.WriteLine("Product Info:");
    foreach (var productInfo in query)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Product Id: {0} Product name: {1} ",
            productInfo.ProductId, productInfo.ProductName);
    }
}
```

I understand that the query gets executed on the database server when the for loop starts executing. Assuming the database server returns the entire result back to the .net application and the entire data is held in `query` variable.

Is there any way to limit this so as to prevent memory overflow issues.

Comment: I'm not sure your assertion is entirely correct.   The /initial/ query may be executed at the time the foreach is executed, but it's possible that you could start processing the database rows before the whole query has been completed (which is the whole point of delayed execution).

Comment: @Sami - I agree that filtering is done at db server, but assuming the filtered resultset is huge, I want to know whether entity framework holds the entire resultset in memory?

Comment: @variable: unless you don't call `ToArray` ,`ToList`,`ToHashSet`,`ToDictionary`,`ToLookup` etc.  you're just streaming the resultset, otherwise you are buffering all into memory. Note that it also means that you will query the DB again if you consume `query` again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/performance/efficient-querying#buffering-and-streaming), using `foreach` directly on an EF `IQueryable` *streams* the data, loading each entity into memory individually.

This reduces memory consumption, with the caveat that the underlying table(s) will be locked for the duration of the loop execution.

Note that as highlighted by David in the comments, you should also disable tracking to make entities eligible for garbage collection after each iteration.

Thais can be done for an individual query using `AsNoTracking`:

```
foreach (var productInfo in query.AsNoTracking())
```

Or globally using [`QueryTrackingBehavior`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.querytrackingbehavior?view=efcore-6.0).

Comment: Note that a reference to each entity will be stored in the Change Tracker as it's materialized form the IEnumerable unless you turn off Change Tracking, eg with [.AsNotracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.asnotracking?view=efcore-6.0)  A reference in the Change Tracker will prevent the object from being GC'd for the lifetime of the DbContext (or until the Change Tracker is cleared).